# Unspecified GSS failure: ... kvno [Number] found in keytab but not with enctype rc4-hmac

Tags: python, security, authentication, kerberos, spring-security-kerberos

I am trying to run a code that verifies an Authorization token from the client.
I wrote this code inside an function:

```
 host = 'site_address'
state = None
service_name = f'HTTP@{host}'
try:
    rc, state = kerberos.authGSSServerInit(service_name)
    if rc != kerberos.AUTH_GSS_COMPLETE:
        return None
    rc = kerberos.authGSSServerStep(state, token)   <<<<< !!! ERROR !!!
    if rc == kerberos.AUTH_GSS_COMPLETE:
        self.kerberos_token = kerberos.authGSSServerResponse(state)
        self.kerberos_user = kerberos.authGSSServerUserName(state)
        return rc
    elif rc == kerberos.AUTH_GSS_CONTINUE:
        return kerberos.AUTH_GSS_CONTINUE
    else:
        return None
except kerberos.GSSError as error:
    LOGGER.error('Failed to perform the token verification due to %s', error)
    return None
finally:
    if state:
        kerberos.authGSSServerClean(state)
```

But the code fails at `rc = kerberos.authGSSServerStep(state, token)` (Marked the line in the code) with this error:

```
GSSError: (('Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information', 851968), ('Request ticket server HTTP/<site_address>@<realm_name> kvno 4 found in keytab but not with enctype rc4-hmac', 100005))
```

Also thrown this error to the screen:

```
[3302] 1547638447.877515: Failed to decrypt AP-REQ ticket: -1765328340/Request ticket server HTTP/base.testing.gc@TESTING.GC kvno 4 found in keytab but not with enctype rc4-hmac
```

My question is: why do I receive this message? My user that is configures in the Active Directory is marked with the `This account supports Kerberos AES 256 bit encryption` enabled and the `keytab` file created with the `/crypto AES256-SHA1` enctype.

Why is my server (docker on ubuntu machine- `Ubuntu 18.04`) is trying to dcrypt this with `rc4-hmac` enctype? How to I fix it?

**Edit** Maybe my question should be: who tells me in which `enctype` should I read the `keytab`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For me it was the `trust configuration` of the browser- should have add the site to the browser's trusted sites (Internet Options -> Security -> Local Internet -> Sites -> Add the site with the exact **port**, **http/https** and **address*).

For some weird reason, the instruction of the enctype are in the token's header... or there is some kind of fallback to this encryption.